# What does "left to center" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was watching a TV show and a man was talking about a singer and he said that singer was a left to center artist. Clearly it was a compliment but I kind of got lost there. What exactly does that mean? By the way, I'm sure this is not related to politics, not in this specific case at least.

Answer (score 2):

They may not have to be Liberal, politically speaking, exactly. But I believe the "weirdness" of having differing-to-mainstream views on subjects of all colours, is the key thing. Then again, politics does permeate everything whether you want it to or not. But Liberal is usually what artists that fit this description tend to go for, if they're not Independent or some other political style or party or what-have-you. Generally you could say Liberal, probably, but just be careful of calling someone a type of person that they may not necessarily be.

UK English.